# No puedo instalar un paquete nuget

Tags: html, nuget

No me es posible instalar el paquete `microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` ya que me indica **"Requiere una asignación del origen del paquete"** y no habilita el botón de instalar pensé que era motivo a que lo tenía con `github` pero aun no me lo permite, he configurado diferentes Orígenes del paquete pero ninguno habilita el botón.

El error que indica es

```
Gravedad    Código  Descripción Proyecto    Archivo Línea   Estado suprimido
Error       No se encontró el paquete 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.12' en los siguientes orígenes principales: 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'. Compruebe que todos los orígenes de paquetes están disponibles o que el id. del paquete y la versión se especificaron correctamente.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estaba teniendo el mismo problema con cualquier paquete NuGet.<br/> Me habilitó a instalar cuando quite todas las asignaciones de origen de paquete.
[![Desactivar asignaciones de origen del paquete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ1jo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQ1jo.png) El mensaje cambia por "La asignación de origen del paquete está desactivada".
[![La asignación de origen del paquete está desactivada](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr5vp.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gr5vp.png)